# Weird corruption of Boolean Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, java-native-interface, boolean

This might sound weird but I am struggling with this bug for past 2 days.

1. I have a `boolean` array in java that is initialised using a `Random` boolean generator.
2. After that the `boolean` array is acted upon by a function in C (called using JNI) and the modified `boolean` array is returned to java. When I hand over the `boolean` array to C, it is converted to unsigned char and converted back to `jbooleanArray` before being handed back to java.
3. Now I run the following code (there is a for loop over i):

   ```
   if(chosen_packet[i] == false)
   {
        pkt.first[i] = 0;
        System.out.print(chosen_packet[i]);
   }
   if(chosen_packet[i] == true)
   {
        pkt.first[i] = 1;
        System.out.print(chosen_packet[i]);
   }
   ```

The problem is that sometimes when `chosen_packet[i]` is `true` it still does not enter the second `if` condition. This happens sometimes and sometimes the code works just fine. When I print `chosen_packet[i]` in such a case it is printed as `true` yet it does not enter the second `if` condition. What could be the possible reason for this seeming corruption of the `boolean` array ?

EDIT: This is how I convert the `boolean` array to `unsigned char` in C:

```
 jboolean *element = (*env)->GetBooleanArrayElements(env,chosen_packet,0);
 for(j = 0; j < sz; j++)
          src_pkt[j] = (unsigned char)element[j];
```

This src_pkt is acted upon and then I convert it back to `jboolean` .

EDIT2: This is how I convert the unsigned char array back to jboolean:

```
 jbooleanArray arr = (*env)->NewBooleanArray(env,sz);
 (*env)->SetBooleanArrayRegion(env,arr,0,sz,src_pkts);
 (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env,arr);
```

Comment: Why you expect your first if to execute when `chosen_packet[i]` is `true`?

Comment: are you sure the chosen_packet is of type Boolean[] ? or boolean[]

Comment: @RohitJain I have edited the question. There was a slight mistake. My apologies for that.

Comment: @fredcrs chosen_packet is of type boolean[]. What is the difference between Boolean[] and boolean[] ?

Comment: and how do you convert it back? by casting `(jboolean) src_pkt[j]`? Because I think that may be wrong.

Comment: @Saintali To cast back to boolean I use the JNI call `SetBooleanArrayRegion` where in I pass the `jboolean` array which is to be populated the `unsigned char` array which contains data.

Comment: The devil is in the details. "`jboolean` array which is to be populated the `unsigned char` array" could mean anything. So PLEASE post you code in C, not in English prose.

Comment: @Saintali I have updated the question to show how I convert the unsigned char array back to jboolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal that if the `boolean` is `true` it does not enter in the first `if` since you are checking for it to be `false` in its condition.

Your code can be simplified to (you should use `if/else` instead of two if checking for the different conditions).

```
if (chosen_packet[i]) {
    pkt.first[i] = 1;
} else {
    pkt.first[i] = 0;
}
System.out.print(chosen_packet[i]);
```

or even

```
pkt.first[i] = chosen_packet[i] ? 1 : 0;
System.out.print(chosen_packet[i]);
```

**Edit**

If your program does not enter the second if, it means that the the var `chosen_packet[i]` is not `true`, you could use a debugger to verify what is the real value.

As stated by *fredcrs*, are you sure that `chosen_packet[i]` is of type `boolean`?

Comment: OP is asking about second `if` block. Why doesn't it enter in second `if` when value is `true`? Your answer is simplify the syntax by not highlighting the issue.

Comment: @YogendraSingh he edited his post since, he first asked about the first `if`

Comment: There was an error in the question. My apologies. It does not enter the second if condition.

Comment: @Alex When I print the `chosen_packet[i]` variable it is printed as true only, yest it does not enter the if condition where I write 'chosen_packet[i] == true'. Is there some other way of debugging I could use ?

Answer (score 1):

Java `boolean` is usually implemented as single byte. So it is possible that there is a bug in your C code that causes the `boolean` to be neither `true` nor `false`. In that case you may encounter undefined behavior.

Note that simply casting `unsigned char` to `jboolean` as in`(jboolean) src_pkt[j]` does not normalize it. You have to use `src_pkt[j] ? JNI_TRUE : JNI_FALSE`.

Still I believe you have to post more of relevant parts of your JNI code.

Comment: I have added the code by which conversion of jboolean to unsigned char takes place in the question above.

Comment: Hi  can you please expand a little on `n ? JNI_TRUE : JNI_FALSE` . What does n represent here ? Should I write something like this: `if(chosen_packet[i] == JNI_TRUE') then src_pkt[i] = 1;`